# Kubernetes pod volume [gcePersistentDisk] zone specification

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, nfs, persistent-volumes

I have set up a nfs-server in our cluster which references a compute disk that's being created by terraform. Here is the script to create the deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nfs-server
  namespace: storage
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      role: nfs-server
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        role: nfs-server
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nfs-server
        image: gcr.io/google_containers/volume-nfs:0.8
        ports:
          - name: nfs
            containerPort: 2049
          - name: mountd
            containerPort: 20048
          - name: rpcbind
            containerPort: 111
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
        volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /exports
            name: nfs-pvc
      volumes:
        - name: nfs-pvc
          gcePersistentDisk:
            pdName: testing-airflow-disk
            fsType: ext4
```

The error I'm encountering is that when a pod is created by this deployment sometimes it is looking for the `gcePersistentDisk` in different zones [`europe-west1-c`, `europe-west1-b`]. The disk resides in `europe-west1-b` so I would like to specify the disk zone but can't seem to find in the docs where that can be done in the deployment yaml.

Comment: I'm not certain, but it seems to me like this is not possible. A pod does not care where it lives, and will be looking for volumes on the node it's deployed on.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found based on Neskews answer was to set a node affinity condition on the deployment to only use nodes which have the same zone label as the disk zone specification. The code for this looks like:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nfs-server
  namespace: storage
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      role: nfs-server
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        role: nfs-server
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nfs-server
        image: gcr.io/google_containers/volume-nfs:0.8
        ports:
          - name: nfs
            containerPort: 2049
          - name: mountd
            containerPort: 20048
          - name: rpcbind
            containerPort: 111
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
        volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /exports
            name: nfs-pvc
      volumes:
        - name: nfs-pvc
          gcePersistentDisk:
            pdName: testing-airflow-disk
            fsType: ext4
      affinity:
        nodeAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            nodeSelectorTerms:
              - matchExpressions:
                  - key: topology.kubernetes.io/zone
                    operator: In
                    values:
                      - europe-west1-b
```